# how C calculate int and float data type mixed

Tags: c

**[SOLVED]**

I'm learning C and I encountered some problems during my learning process.

When I'm trying to calculate an int datatype and float datatype in one equation, I ended up getting 2 different outputs. and I'm confused because logically the result should be the same.

here is my code version 1 and version 2. The difference lies in the variable z.

- the first case: the value of z is 1
- the second case: the value of z   is 0

**All the input is 11**

**UPDATE 1**

thank you all for your comments and answers. but I'm still confused about what role the variable `p`plays in case 1 and how could it led to the variable `z` to be 1 rather than 0?

**Case 1**

```
int main()
{
    float a, fee, p;
    int x, y,z;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    fee = 0.6 * a;
    x = (int)(fee);
    y = (int)(2 * fee - 2 * x);
    p = fee * 10.0;
    z = (int)(p - 10 * x - 5 * y);
    printf("%f %d %d %d", fee, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

**Case 2**

```
int main()
{
    float a, fee, p;
    int x, y,z;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    fee = 0.6 * a;
    x = (int)(fee);
    y = (int)(2 * fee - 2 * x);
    z = (int)(fee * 10.0 - 10 * x - 5 * y);
    printf("%f %d %d %d", fee, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And *please* don't add irrelevant tags to your questions. If you ask about a program in C, use only the C language tag. Also note that there's no such languages as "C/C++", only the two distinct and *very* different languages C and C++. If you want to learn one, that's fine. but don't try to learn both simultaneously.

Comment: Your second code will not build. Please also learn how to create a proper [mre], that you copy-paste into the question (after testing it yourself to make sure it replicates only the problem you ask about).

Comment: You also should show us an example of input and expected vs. actual output for both cases.

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't learn C/C++, you learn one or the other. Although that have commonalities, the mindset is totally different.

Comment: It's no good idea to mix integer and float in the same line, as you saw yourself it's not too easy to determine how the compiler works. Of course there are deterministic rules what happens, just read the standard.
A more easy way is, to copy the integers to float variables or float to integer and calculate the whole thing in float or integer. Then you know for sure which operation is taken in which mode.

Comment: In your code for case 2, on the line `z = (int)(fee * 10.0; - 10 * x - 5 * y);`, don't you want to remove the semicolon in the middle of the line?

Comment: 1) Fix your second code example... it can't compile! 2) What is your input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1) z = (int)(p - 10 * x - 5 * y);
             F    I   I   I   I            // Float or Int

2) z = (int)(fee * 10.0 - 10 * x - 5 * y); // semicolon removed
              F     D      I   I   I   I   // Float, Double or Int
```

All calculations in 1) are done in `float` precision, in 2) in `double` precision.

**Suggestion: always prefer `double` when using floating-point values.**

Comment: I'd even go as far as: forget `float` exists :-)

Comment: "All calculations in 1) are done in float precision, in 2) in double precision." The integer multiplications are done with "integer" precision. In other words `10 * x` and `(float)10 * x` may generate different results depending on the value of `x`

Answer (score 1):

if you cast a floating point number less then 1 like 0.9f to INT, it will become zero.